# Adding Holes to a custom EAGLE library

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication, cad, device-characteristics

Currently, I am creating a custom EAGLE library for a relay that I couldn't find the CAD for.

In the packag stage:
I added the pads as seen in the picture and I'm having second thoughts about adding the holes.

My thinking is that they needed to be added for the milling machine to know where to drill but none of the tutorials I have seen have added them.

What is the way to go about it? [image]

Comment: I've never used EAGLE, but at least in KiCAD any pads you add automatically include drill holes in them. I would assume other EDA software does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finished design and after checking the file layers, the pads do in fact contain through holes and there is no need to add extra ones.